# node: fast-json-stringify disable schema validation by ajv

Tags: javascript, node.js, fastify

I want use [fastify/fast-json-stringify](https://github.com/fastify/fast-json-stringify) just for stringify javascript object without validate the JSON schema.

Any way for serialize without validate?

Comment: What do you mean? FJS does not validate objects (unless you use $anyOf or $oneOf)

Comment: I use $anyOf ...

Comment: You must provide a custom ajv instance then